# Dynamic number of cells on fixed number of columns

Tags: html, css, layout

Is it possible to distribute dynamic number of cells inside a container with fixed number of columns (say 4). What I want to do is something like:

```
<div class="container_4">
    <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 3</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 4</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 5</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 6</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 7</div>
</div>
```

without specifying where the row ends after every 4 cells, this should look like:

```
Cell 1    Cell 2    Cell 3    Cell 4
Cell 5    Cell 6    Cell 7
```

Comment: Is the container's width fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm getting it right, this might work for you:

```
#container_4 {
    width: 400px; /* Change to your container width */
}

.cell {
    width: 25%; /* Use different percentages for a different number of columns */
    float: left;
}
```

Then, if you need margins on your cell, either do the math, ex:

```
.cell {
    width: 23%; /* 1/4 the container width - margin x 2 */
    margin: 1%; /* Your margin */
    float: left;
}
```

Or use the CSS3 property `box-sizing` and give your box margins with padding's instead:

```
.cell {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 1%;
    float: left;
    /* This will make the specified with include padding's and borders */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Standard syntax */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari */
}
```

*NOTE: The `box-sizing` property will not work on **ie7**. When in quirks mode, **ie6** uses the "`border-box`" model by defaul (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) for more info in ie6 box model bug).*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do I need something for the container css? This made all items on the same row.

Comment: You need to specify the width of your container. Sorry I read your comment before and just assumed you had already made that.

Comment: Edited my answer to include that last fix. Also, if you were not working with floats on your page already you might want to include a "clear fix" technique on your #container_4 css. [This one](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) normally works for me.

Comment: I believe IE6 behaves like IE7, with proper doctype (and I guess you want one at beginning of your HTML code). Though yes, IE6 in quirks mode will behave as border-box by default, very ironically...

Answer (score 1):

### CSS

```
.container_4{
width:480px;
height:160px;
background:#EFEFEF;
}

.cell{
border:solid 1px #999;
float:left;
height:58px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
width:98px;
background-color:White;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/MyX7N/)